# JPA WrongClassException - inheritance

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I've got an `Account` abstract class which is inherited by two other classes:
`DoctorAccount`, `NurseAccount` (i omited getters and setters in order to keep post brief). After performing the method  `checkIfLoginAndPasswordIsCorrect` i get an error:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass [Model.Account] : Discriminator: 1`. I found out that `query.getSingleResult();` is responsible for this, but I dont know why it throws such errors. Using polymorphism I can assign Account to Doctor/Nurse. Do You have any idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "Type_of_account", discriminatorType = 
DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Account {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name="Id")
     private int id;
     @Column(name="Login")
     private String login;
     @Column(name="Password")
     private String password;
}

@Entity
public class NurseAccount extends Account{
}

@Entity
public class DoctorAccount extends Account{
}
```

In logInDAO class:

```
@Override
public boolean checkIfLoginAndPasswordIsCorrect(String login, String password) {
    Account account = null;
    EntityManagerFactory managerFacotry = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager");
    EntityManager manager = managerFacotry.createEntityManager();
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    Query query =  manager.createQuery("SELECT a from Account a WHERE a.login = :login AND a.password = :password")
            .setParameter("login", login).setParameter("password", password);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
    try {
         account = (Account) query.getSingleResult(); // HERE Occures error
    }
    catch(NoResultException lackOfResult){  
        return false;
    }
    if(account != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: are you sure that there are no multiple results being returned

Comment: Yes, in database I've got only one record

Comment: Wonder what SQL is invoked. Maybe it is found in the LOG

Comment: Using a different JPA provider this generates SQL of the form `SELECT A.ID,A.LOGIN,A.PASSWORD,A.TYPE_OF_ACCOUNT FROM ACCOUNT A WHERE ((A.TYPE_OF_ACCOUNT = 'DoctorAccount' OR A.TYPE_OF_ACCOUNT = 'NurseAccount')) AND A.LOGIN = <'doc1'> AND A.PASSWORD = <'password'>`. This returns a `DoctorAccount` object. Consequently you can conclude that it is a shortcoming in your JPA provider. Report a bug on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add
`@org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)` on your Account class

Comment: Why would someone need to use some Hibernate-specific thing when using the JPA API? They shouldn't. Ever.

Comment: I agree but considering the circumstances I just suggested an approach if an ideal solution is not met with

Comment: So is there solution for JPA specification?

Comment: @Michael213 To see the JPA "solution" you need to DEFINE the precise problem, since you have not given info as to WHY your JPA provider is getting it wrong; perhaps, just perhaps, other JPA providers get it right on that input? aka bug in your provider that this provider-specific property "fixes"

Comment: Not that I am aware of as of today but I recall from past experience this worked for me as well. One thing though that there are times when there is a mismatch between the size of discriminator column and the data being inserted. If that is the case then spaces get added but not sure that applies in this case.

Comment: which you find out by actually looking at the SQL invoked, and the data in the database (which the OP doesn't provide).